# Binary classification with softmax activation always outputs 1

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, deep-learning

Sorry for the quality of the question but a beginner here , I was just trying my luck with titanic dataset, but it always predicts that the passenger died. I try to explain code below:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns


import tensorflow as tf

from tensorflow import keras
from tensorflow.keras import layers
from tensorflow.keras import losses
from tensorflow.keras.layers.experimental import preprocessing

import os
```

Load dataset

```
dataset_dir = os.path.join(os.getcwd(), 'titanic')
train_url = os.path.join(dataset_dir, 'train.csv')
test_url = os.path.join(dataset_dir, 'test.csv')


raw_train_dataset = pd.read_csv(train_url)
raw_test_dataset = pd.read_csv(test_url)


train = raw_train_dataset.copy()
test = raw_test_dataset.copy()
```

Dropping some columns , I may be wrong here

```
train = train.drop(['Cabin','Name','Ticket'], 1)
test = test.drop(['Cabin','Name','Ticket'], 1)
```

Hot vector

```
train = pd.get_dummies(train, prefix='', prefix_sep='')
test = pd.get_dummies(test, prefix='', prefix_sep='')
```

training labels

```
train_predict = train.pop('Survived')
```

Filling null ages with mean

```
train['Age'].fillna((train['Age'].mean()), inplace=True)
test['Age'].fillna((train['Age'].mean()), inplace=True)
```

Dropping null columns

```
test = test.dropna()
train = train.dropna()
```

Creating Normalisation layer

```
normalizer = preprocessing.Normalization()
normalizer.adapt(np.array(train))
```

Creating dnn , am I wrong here

```
model = keras.Sequential([
      normalizer,
      layers.Dense(64, activation='relu'),
      layers.Dropout(0.2),
      layers.Dense(1)
  ])



model.compile(loss=losses.BinaryCrossentropy(from_logits=True),
              optimizer='adam',
              metrics=tf.metrics.BinaryAccuracy(threshold=0.0))


history = model.fit(
    train, train_predict,
    validation_split=0.2,
     epochs=30)
```

This shows 1 in every case but I still get accuracy of 85% when training , I don't need complete solution of the problem(I want to try on my own) but just the part where I am stuck

```
result = tf.nn.softmax(model(train))
print(result)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`tf.nn.softmax` will always return an array of `sum=1`. Since your output is 1 value (you have one unit on your final/output layer), a softmax operation will transform this value to 1.

```
for value in [.2, .999, .0001, 100., -100.]:
    print(tf.nn.softmax([value]))
```

```
tf.Tensor([1.], shape=(1,), dtype=float32)
tf.Tensor([1.], shape=(1,), dtype=float32)
tf.Tensor([1.], shape=(1,), dtype=float32)
tf.Tensor([1.], shape=(1,), dtype=float32)
tf.Tensor([1.], shape=(1,), dtype=float32)
```

What you're looking for is `tf.nn.sigmoid`:

```
for value in [.2, .999, .0001, 100., -100.]:
    print(tf.nn.sigmoid([value]))
```

```
tf.Tensor([0.549834], shape=(1,), dtype=float32)
tf.Tensor([0.7308619], shape=(1,), dtype=float32)
tf.Tensor([0.500025], shape=(1,), dtype=float32)
tf.Tensor([1.], shape=(1,), dtype=float32)
tf.Tensor([0.], shape=(1,), dtype=float32)
```

`losses.BinaryCrossentropy(from_logits=True)` is like sigmoid crossentropy.

If you want to round the values to get 0 or 1, use `tf.round`:

```
tf.round(tf.nn.sigmoid([.1]))
```

Comment: Thank you nicolas but it gives me decimal values between 0 to 1 , I need to predict just 0 or 1

Comment: just one more question why is `tf.round(tf.nn.sigmoid([.1]))` not included in the model but outside it

Comment: you could have done it if you wanted. add `activation='sigmoid'` in your last layer, and your loss function `from_logits=False`

Comment: it fails when I do this , I get binary accuracy 35%

Comment: No, it doesn't.

Comment: No problem I would stick with above solution for now thanks a lot