# training on imdb dataset with tensorflow2/keras give strange result

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, tensorflow2.0, tf.keras

I'm new to tensorflow2/keras. I was following this [tutorial](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/keras/text_classification) on tensorflow website. Instead of downloading the text data to directory, I use `tensorflow_datasets` to load imdb dataset directly to tensors/numpy arrays. Below is my code.

```
import os
import re
import string
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf
import tensorflow_hub as hub
import tensorflow_datasets as tfds

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from tensorflow.keras import layers
from tensorflow.keras.layers.experimental.preprocessing import TextVectorization

print("Version: ", tf.__version__)
print("Eager mode: ", tf.executing_eagerly())
print("Hub version: ", hub.__version__)
print("GPU is", "available" if tf.config.list_physical_devices('GPU') else "NOT AVAILABLE")

train_data, test_data = tfds.load(name="imdb_reviews", split=["train", "test"], 
                                  batch_size=-1, as_supervised=True)

X_train, y_train = tfds.as_numpy(train_data)
X_test, y_test = tfds.as_numpy(test_data)

# process text
def custom_standardization(input_data):
  lowercase = tf.strings.lower(input_data)
  stripped_html = tf.strings.regex_replace(lowercase, '<br />', ' ')
  return tf.strings.regex_replace(stripped_html,
                                  '[%s]' % re.escape(string.punctuation),
                                  '')
max_features = 1000
sequence_length = 50

vectorize_layer = TextVectorization(
    standardize=custom_standardization,
    max_tokens=max_features,
    output_mode='int',
    output_sequence_length=sequence_length)
# Make a text-only dataset (without labels), then call adapt
vectorize_layer.adapt(X_train)

def vectorize_text(text):
  text = tf.expand_dims(text, -1)
  return vectorize_layer(text)

#check data
first_review, first_label = X_train[0], y_train[0]
print("Review", first_review)
print("Vectorized review", vectorize_text(first_review))
print("11 ---> ",vectorize_layer.get_vocabulary()[11])
print(" 44 ---> ",vectorize_layer.get_vocabulary()[44])
print('Vocabulary size: {}'.format(len(vectorize_layer.get_vocabulary())))


# vectorize both train and test text data
X_train = vectorize_text(X_train)
X_test = vectorize_text(X_test)


embedding_dim = 16
#define and compile model
model = tf.keras.Sequential([
  layers.Embedding(max_features + 1, embedding_dim),
  layers.GlobalAveragePooling1D(),
  layers.Dropout(0.2),
  layers.Dense(256, activation='relu'),
  layers.Dropout(0.2),
  layers.Dense(1)])
model.summary()
model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='categorical_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])
# fit the model
history = model.fit(X_train, y_train, epochs=5, batch_size=32, verbose=2, validation_data=(X_test, y_test))
```

The output I got is like below:

```
_________________________________________________________________
Epoch 1/5
782/782 - 4s - loss: 0.0000e+00 - accuracy: 0.5000 - val_loss: 0.0000e+00 - val_accuracy: 0.5000
Epoch 2/5
782/782 - 4s - loss: 0.0000e+00 - accuracy: 0.5000 - val_loss: 0.0000e+00 - val_accuracy: 0.5000
Epoch 3/5
782/782 - 4s - loss: 0.0000e+00 - accuracy: 0.5000 - val_loss: 0.0000e+00 - val_accuracy: 0.5000
Epoch 4/5
782/782 - 4s - loss: 0.0000e+00 - accuracy: 0.5000 - val_loss: 0.0000e+00 - val_accuracy: 0.5000
Epoch 5/5
782/782 - 4s - loss: 0.0000e+00 - accuracy: 0.5000 - val_loss: 0.0000e+00 - val_accuracy: 0.5000
```

Accuracy are all 50%! Something went wrong.  I'm confused why that happened? I was following the tutorial, train the embedding layer from scratch.  Spent hours trying to figuring out why.
Does anyone know why went wrong? thanks!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Binary classification with softmax activation always outputs 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65599903/binary-classification-with-softmax-activation-always-outputs-1)

Comment: Accuracy is 50% all the time because your network outputs **1** every time as you use `softmax` with 1 neuron.

Comment: Thanks for help.   I removed `activation='softmax'`  it still output the same result!

Comment: I editted my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your dense layer is `linear` which means you don't have any activation passed into it. There are several solutions, as you are doing `binary_classification`.

If you want to use `Dense(1)` as it is, then you should change loss function into:

```
model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss=tf.keras.losses.BinaryCrossentropy(from_logits=True),
              metrics=['accuracy'])
```

Or you can use `Dense(1, activation = tf.nn.sigmoid)`, then your loss function should be:

```
model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='binary_crossentropy',
              metrics=['accuracy'])
```

Or another solution if your labels are one hot encoded, you can set `Dense(2, activation = tf.nn.softmax)` then loss function can be:

```
model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='categorical_crossentropy',
              metrics=['accuracy'])
```

I reproduced the exact code of yours with changings:

```
  layers.Dense(1, activation = tf.nn.sigmoid)])
  model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='binary_crossentropy', metrics= 
                                   ['accuracy'])
```

Got:

```
782/782 [==============================] - 4s 5ms/step - loss: 0.4836 - accuracy: 0.7675 - val_loss: 0.5065 - val_accuracy: 0.7447
```

Edit 2: `sigmoid` squeezes your output into a range of [0,1]. For example to get predictions you need all `x_test`. `X_test[0]` will mess up the predictions as it only contains the first sentence. Get predictions by using:

```
y_hat = model.predict(X_test)
y_hat

array([[0.8105568 ],
       [0.6332975 ],
       [0.20526059],
       ...,
       [0.03132877],
       [0.5318063 ],
       [0.8626927 ]], dtype=float32)
```

Now set a threshold and convert them into 0 and 1s. This can be done with:

```
y_pred = [1 * (x[0]>=0.5) for x in y_hat]
```

`y_pred` will be containing zeros and ones. Note that threshold is 0.5 here which means if output from `sigmoid` is bigger than 0.5, than it belongs to second class.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help. However, I tried and use `activation = tf.nn.sigmoid`, still got the same result. There might be something else wrong. would you please run the code to see if you can reproduce the output? thx  @Frightera

Comment: I reproduced and got the expected output, maybe you forgot the change the loss function?

Comment: Thanks! I also reproduced just now. I accidentally put 'categorical_crossentropy'  as loss. Should have been 'binary_crossentropy'. I have a follow-up question: Hope you do not mind.   I made prediction `yhat = model.predict(X_test[0])`. The result seems to be a numpy array of shape (50,1).  Should the yhat be either 0 or 1? I'm confused....   Thank you so much for your help!  @Frightera

Comment: I've now added and explained how you can convert them into 0 and 1s as well. I would be happy if you accept and upvote the answer.

Comment: Thanks a lot!   I just accepted and upvoted your answer.  Could you explain a little more why predict on X_test[0] mess up with the prediction and give a (50,1) numpy array? it's just a subset of X_test. (first row). @Frightera

Comment: Because the model is behaving it as a complete `X_test`, therefore it is trying to give predictions to every word(I think). If you want to have **only** first row's prediction, then you should do: `model.predict(np.array([X_test[0]]))`. That should return a value between [0,1] for the first row of the `X_test`.

Comment: I got it. THank you!